# SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE notes

Tags: mysql, sql, flutter, dart, sqflite

The error

```
Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE notlar(
      id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      onenote TEXT NOT NULL
    )) sql '    CREATE TABLE notlar(
      id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      onenote TEXT NOT NULL
    )
    ' args [])
```

This is my code for create the table with flutter package sqflite. I have readData, deleteData, updateData and insertData functions for table. But I am getting error. There are a lot of options to solve the problem but I  don't solve the problem. I tried a lot of options to solve.

```
class SqlDb {
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = await initialDb();
      return _db;
    } else {
      return _db;
    }
  }

  initialDb() async {
    String databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasePath, 'wael.db');
    Database mydb = await openDatabase(path,
        onCreate: _onCreate, version: 2, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
    return mydb;
  }

   _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    print("ronaldo");
  }


  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE notlar(
      id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      onenote TEXT NOT NULL
    )
    ''');
    print("created database and table");
  }

  

  readData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    List<Map> response = await mydb!.rawQuery(sql);
    return response;
  }

  insertData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    int response = await mydb!.rawInsert(sql);
    return response;
  }

  updateData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    int response = await mydb!.rawUpdate(sql);
    return response;
  }

  deleteData(String sql) async {
    Database? mydb = await db;
    int response = await mydb!.rawDelete(sql);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried moving the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword after the primary key? Like `id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Reference: [package github issue](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/765#issuecomment-1019363864)

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepeted then? Thanks